# shell script magento cant load product model

Tags: magento-1, shell, mage-shell

in shell directory is file myscript.php with code

```
<?php
require_once 'abstract.php';

class MyModule_Shell_Myscript extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{
    protected $_argname = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        set_time_limit(0);     
        if ($this->getArg('argname')) {
            $this->_argname = array_merge(
                $this->_argname,
                array_map(
                    'trim',
                    explode(',', $this->getArg('argname'))
                )
            );
        }
    }

    public function run()
    {            
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('2'); 
        var_dump($product->getData());
    }
}

$shell = new MyModule_Shell_Myscript();
$shell->run();
```

Product with this id is in database
When i try to run command `php shell/myscript.php` 
I got error [image]

Comment: Where does `$product_id` get set? That error doesn't look related to your shell script but rather another extension.

Comment: Regadless of not set `$product_id` the script works for me.

Comment: @Paul i edited script

Answer (score 1):

I hope you already solved shell script issue.

Added comma separated value as well in loop along with the usageHelp.

```
<?php
require_once 'abstract.php';

class MyModule_Shell_Myscript extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{
    protected $_argname = array();
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        set_time_limit(0);     
        if ($this->getArg('argname')) {
            $this->_argname = array_merge( $this->_argname, array_map('trim', explode(',', $this->getArg('argname') ) ) );
        }
    }

    public function run()
    {   
        if ($this->getArg('argname')) {
            try {
                foreach( $this->_argname as $row) {
                    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load( $row );
                    var_dump( $product->getData() );
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            echo $this->usageHelp();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Get Usage Help Message
     *
     */
    public function usageHelp()
    {
        return <<<USAGE
Usage:  php product.php -- [options]

  --argname 12,14,15    Comma separated product ids

USAGE;
    }

}

$shell = new MyModule_Shell_Myscript();
$shell->run();
```

Comment: thanks, but $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product') returned null, empty object

Comment: Forget to mention that what should pass params while executing
it should be like as : 
`php product.php --argname 12,34,45`